# A way to synchronize read and modify with mutex

Tags: c, thread-safety

I'm implementing synchronisation of a web proxy server cache. There are two cases:

1. If the cache is being modified, it can't be modified by other
   threads
2. If the cache is being read, it can't be modified by other
   threads, but it can be read by other threads.

I want to make the cache readable even though it is being read by other threads.

```
int readflag = 0;
// read
void read()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock();
    pthread_mutex_unlock();
    ++readflag;
    /* read the cache*/
    --readflag;
}

// modify
void write()
{
    while(readflag > 0);
    pthread_mutex_lock();
    /* modify the cache*/
    pthread_mutex_unlock();
}
```

This is my simple code. However, it seems awkward and is also not thread-safe. 
How can I implement this synchronization?

Comment: @Lundin Oh, sorry. I questioned ambiguously. I meant that the "Cache" is a web proxy server cache, not a hardware cache memory.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing what you are looking for is a "semaphore", not a mutex. I don't remember what they are called in the pthread lib.

Comment: @Lundin I already know the semaphore, but I don't know if I can implement with it. The problem is, it is not possible to differentiate read lock from modify lock with a semaphore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pthreads provides read-write locks for this purpose.

Your example with pthreads read-write locks:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

static pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

static void read()
{
    int r;
    r=pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock); 
    assert(0==r); 
    //lock/unlock ops can't fail
    //unless your program's logic is flawed

    /* read the cache*/
    r=pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock); assert(0==r);
}

// modify
static void write()
{
    int r;
    r=pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock); assert(0==r);
    /* modify the cache*/
    r=pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock); assert(0==r);
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you!